# to check how many roots are real

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileOutputStreamExample
{
  public static int count;

  public void equation(int a, int b,int c)
  {

    int e=(b*b)-(4*a*c);
    double f=Math.pow(e,1/2);
    if(f>=0)
        count=count++;

  }
 public static void main (String []args)
 {
    FileOutputStreamExample fos= new FileOutputStreamExample();
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int N= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
       int a= sc.nextInt();
       int b= sc.nextInt();
       int c= sc.nextInt();
       fos.equation(a, b, c);
    }

    System.out.println("ans is "+count);
   }
}
```

Here i am writing a code to check if given N inputs of a quadratic equation having having coefficients a,b,c then how many of the given N inputs have real roots.
This code compiles as good as possible but results in ans=0 all the time. The count is not working in this case.

Comment: `count = count++` does NOTHING -> `count = count+1` OR `count++` only ;) read about post-incrementation

Comment: `count = count++;` is nonsense - it stores the old value of count into a temporary location, increments count by one and overwrites it with the old value. Either write `count = count+1;` or `count++;` or even `count += 1;`

Comment: The roots will have a non-zero imaginary component if b²-4∙a∙c is less than zero. You are also not calculating the square root correctly as @yshavit points out, but you don't need to to see if the root is real - it's easier to test if the value going into the square root is negative vs testing whether the square root results in a NaN

Answer (score 4):

`count=count++;`

This line actually does nothing. It increments the `count`, but it also returns a value as an expression, which is then stored back in `count`. Since the ++ is at the end, that value being stored is the original value of count, thus undoing the increment. :)

When using the increment (or decrement) operators, you don't have to use an assignment operator to modify the value. The increment itself implies a modification to the variable.

Fix it by changing it to: `count++;`

In addition to that, `1/2` will always be equal to zero, since the operands are integers, and as such, the division applied is an integer division (which truncates decimal parts) rather than the division you're probably expecting.

Change that to `1.0/2` or just `.5`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your code should get compiled. You are invoking a static variable in non static method.
Further,either write count++,count+=1or count=count+1.